# Unknown server tag in webformsmvp

Tags: asp.net, webforms, mvp, webformsmvp

** Updated **

- For some reason cutting and pasting the web.config did it.

I'm trying to use the mvp:pagedatasource control

```
<mvp:PageDataSource ID="odsReplacementRequests" runat="server" EnablePaging="true">
```

but I get an

**"Unknown server tag 'mvpPageDataSource' error on the page.**

I installed this using nuget manager and have the webformsmvp assembly. My user control also inherits from the mvp:usercontrol

```
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="mvp" namespace="WebFormsMvp.Web" assembly="WebFormsMvp" />
            <add tagPrefix="mvp" namespace="WebFormsMvp" assembly="WebFormsMvp" />
        </controls>         
    </pages>




 [PresenterBinding(typeof(GPReplacementRequestsPresenter))]
    public partial class Controls_GPReplacementList :  MvpUserControl<GPReplacementRequestsModel>, IGPReplacementRequestsView

{ 

    /// <summary>
    /// Page Load
    /// </summary>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
```

Comment: You're missing a tag prefix registration in the ASPX or in Web.config.

Comment: I've added the following controls to the web.config, but it still doesn't work. Is there anything I need to do in the aspx page?

Comment: I got it working, it was a combination of what you said plus refreshing the web.config by coping in a new one and then copying back the old one. I'm not sure why it needed that.